# Testing Xamarin Geofence prototye in emulator fails

Tags: android, xamarin, android-geofence

I have a prototype application that uses Geofencing set up in AndroidStudio and have been able to succesfully test it in the Android Emulator. Because I need the application to also be iOS i have ported the prototype to Xamarin/Visual Studio 2017 to make sure that it works in that environment so I can save myself from having to code the core logic of the app in Android and iOS. However I am not able to get the Geofences to fire in the Xamarin based app on the same emulator. Has anyone worked with this technology in Xamarin? are there specific settings that need to change for Xamarin to make this work?

Comment: Did you try on a real device? does it work? Just to discard code issues...

Comment: In the emulator you can try with Settings > Location > Mode > High accuracy

Comment: I am working on testing it on a real device just to make sure. In the emulator I have set the Mode to High Accuracy and it did not change the results.

Comment: Did you try uninstalling/installing on the emulator after chaning location mode?

Comment: Several times, I have also made sure the package name is in lower case (read somewhere that might be a problem), named the Intent Service in the manifest instead of letting Xamarin generate it. I have also tried a Broadcast Receiver instead of an Intent Service as I read that was the way to do it in Xamarin but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is probably coming from the manifest. 
In Xamarin, when you create a service (or intent service) it should be tagged with the attribute `[Service]`, instead of adding it to the manifest manually.

You should also check for errors when handling the intent (in case you are not doing it already):

```
[Service]
public class GeofenceTransitionsIntentService : IntentService, IEnableDatabaseLogger
{
    public GeofenceTransitionsIntentService()
        : base(nameof(GeofenceTransitionsIntentService)) { }

    protected override void OnHandleIntent(Intent intent)
    {
        base.OnHandleIntent(intent);

        this.Log().Info("Intent received");

        var geofencingEvent = GeofencingEvent.FromIntent(intent);
        if (geofencingEvent.HasError)
        {
            var errorMessage = GeofenceErrorMessages.GetErrorString(this, geofencingEvent.ErrorCode);
            this.Log().Error(errorMessage);

            return;
        }

        var geofenceTransition = geofencingEvent.GeofenceTransition;
        var geofences = geofencingEvent.TriggeringGeofences;
        var location = geofencingEvent.TriggeringLocation;

        if (geofenceTransition == Geofence.GeofenceTransitionEnter)
        {
            foreach (var geofence in geofences)
                this.Log().Info($"Entered {geofence.RequestId} at {location.Latitude}/{location.Longitude}");

            // do something
        }
        else if (geofenceTransition == Geofence.GeofenceTransitionExit)
        {
            foreach (var geofence in geofences)
                this.Log().Info($"Exited {geofence.RequestId} at {location.Latitude}/{location.Longitude}");

            // do something
        }
        else
        {
            this.Log().Error($"Geofence transition invalid type: {geofenceTransition}");
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a demo (working) project I did recently: https://github.com/xleon/geofencing-playground

Comment: Thank you for the POC, this has at least helped me isolate that there is something wrong with both the emulator and my solution. Your solution did not work on my emulator but it did work on a device which I have been unable to do so far. I will analyze you code to see how it is different. Hopefully in the meantime I can figure out what is wrong with my emulators.

Comment: My POC didn´t work in the emulator until I changed the settings location mode to High accuracy

Comment: Are you using the Android Emulator or the Visual Studio Emulator for Android?

Comment: Visual Studio emulator

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that.